# How to convert string variable to html within html using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I pass a list of stings to the page of the following form:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for x in post_list %}
        <p > {{x}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

where x is a string that contains HTML code (e.g. `x = "<h1> Some Title </h1>"`). The program does not consider `x` as HTML but some string keeping tags, etc. Is it possible to complie each x to make it display as HTML (so,  `x = <h1> Some Title </h1>` will be displayed as

## Some Title

?

Comment: Try the following filter within your template. `{{ x|safe }}`

Comment: It works! Only thing it does not consider style argument. For example x is moved to center of the page using ```<h1 style="margin-left: 450px;"> Some Title </h1>```, however it seems like``` |safe``` does not consider the style, as it appears not in the center...

Comment: UPD: <div class="container"> helped :)